# Avoid running same job by two EC2 instances

Tags: apscheduler

I am using APScheduler in decorator way to run jobs at certain intervals. The problem is that when below code is deployed in two EC2 instances then same job runs twice at same with difference in milliseconds.

My question is : How to avoid running same job by two EC2 instances at same time or Do I need to follow different code design pattern in this case. I want to run this job only once either by one of the severs.

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.start()    

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', id='my_job_id', hours=2)
def job_function():
  print("Hello World")
```

If you can share any locking mechanism examples it would be appreciable

Comment: You need to provide details about how your scheduler is configured and how it is run. The info you have provided is not enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Why are you deploying the same scheduler in two servers?

Comment: @ Ярослав Рахматуллин
As shown in code I am using apscheduler with annotations to configure and run job. 
@JRichardsz, It is single code but usually in production we have 2 severs and application code is deployed in both servers so if one goes down another one can be backup. So how to deal with schedulers in this case

Comment: I think you need to design new infrastructure. Microservice maybe a good option for this. Just implement a scheduler microservice and deploy it separately with your application.

Comment: As you can see in above code scheduler is part of a function. Since same code gets deployed in multiple servers how to avoid multiple schedulers running same job. Since builds are automated I can't keep modifiying code for deploying in multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS-SDK/AWS-CLI by using AWS-SDK/AWS-CLI you can set

```
If instance_id = "your instance id"
 Write your code here
```

Now your cron will get execute on each instances you have and your code will be executed from that specific instance.

Comment: what if instance id changes during autoscaling of servers.

Comment: In my practice, I always have a primary or default instance from where I create template for autoscaling, if I have default instance, its means i have instance id. And Autoscale will not get conflict here.

Comment: Alternate, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859011/auto-scaling-service-in-aws-without-duplicating-cron-jobs

Comment: As you can see in above code scheduler is part of a function. Since same code gets deployed in multiple servers how to avoid multiple schedulers running same job. Since builds are automated I can't keep modifiying code for deploying in multiple servers

Comment: install this  `pip3 install ec2-metadata`

use below in your script

`from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata`

`if( ec2_metadata.instance_id == "your primary instance id"){
   // put your code here
}`

Comment: The solution seems feasible but is it good practice to hard code instance id in application code?

Comment: For this scenario you have to do this, if you don't want to hard code in your script file add instance id in environment file and call environment variable in your script.